# Nested loops not looping correctly in VBA - either one works or the other

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, nested-loops

I have a project I'm doing in steps of complexity. For this step, I'm trying to get a program to repeat a certain number of times (which I'm trying to use a Do Until Loop for) within a certain number of rows (which I'm using a For loop for). The number of rows is larger (much larger) than the number of times I want the program to loop. The reason I'm trying to use two loops is because I want to search through every row in the i range for various criteria, but I only want to change the first n number of matches. Because I have no idea where or how far apart the matches will be, I need to search the full 9000+ range.

So far, the for loop alone works, but I can't figure out how to successfully add the Do Until loop. I've tried with the For loop on both the inside and the outside, and neither one worked.

In this example, the for loop is on the inside. It was supposed to do 9, and did 9,057 instead (the value of E):

```
    Sub Hilight()

Dim usch As Worksheet
Set usch = Worksheets("USCH attributes")
Dim m As Worksheet
Set m = Worksheets("Maps")

Dim i As Integer
Dim E As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim s3 As String
s1 = Range("U1").Value
s2 = Range("V1").Value
s3 = Range("W1").Value

Dim rU As String
Dim rE As String
Dim rA As String
rU = m.Range("D4").Value
rE = m.Range("D3").Value
rA = m.Range("D2").Value

E = Range("S1").Value
n = 0
        Do Until n >= 9  
        For i = 1 To E
            n = n + 1
            Debug.Print n
            If Cells(i, 15).Value = s3 And Cells(i, 13).Value = rA And Cells(i, 11) = "" Then   
                Cells(i, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If     
        Next i
        Loop
End Sub
```

This next example with the for loop on the outside was sort of better, I guess? The debug only printed up to 9, so that's good. Unfortunately, the For loop doesn't seem to have run at all, since nothing changed colour. (pasting only the inside code, since all the dims are the same)

```
 For i = 1 To E
    Do Until n >= 9
        n = n + 1
        Debug.Print n
        If Cells(i, 15).Value = s3 And Cells(i, 13).Value = rA And Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
            Cells(i, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
    Loop  
    Next i
```

I thought about putting the n = 0 inside the loop, but that would just print 1 nine thousand times, right?

Can you guys please help me fix this to run correctly? I've been reading loop tutorials for three days and I just can't get it to work :( I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you make some [MCVE]? And explain what the two loops should be doing, in one sentence, up to 20 words.

Comment: i loop should be searching for matches through a range and n loop should limit how many times the i loop iterates. Wow this isn’t right at all, is it

Comment: `n` should probably not be increased on every `For` loop, but only after (of before). I think you should have use 2 `For` loop, it would have been best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I would do something very similar to the answer provided by CLR but slightly change it like below, so you would go through `i = 1 to E`, but as soon as `n = 9` I would exit the loop in order to save on resources:

```
n = 0

For i = 1 To E
    If Cells(i, 15).Value = s3 And Cells(i, 13).Value = rA And Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
        Cells(i, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        n = n + 1
    End If

    If n = 9 Then Exit For
Next i
```

Comment: I was going down that route until I read *"I want to search through every row in the i range for various criteria"* -  I assume there will be more `If` statements for other 'various criteria' inside the loop later.. But the question is quite ambiguous.

Comment: I’m planning to use variables referring to cells on the spreadsheet, so I (or more likely someone else) can change the criteria without going into VBA

Comment: @Sylphie yes it would still work, simply replace `n = 9` to `n = yourvariable`

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea if I'm reading your question correctly so this is a guess at your requirement.

The following reads all the lines (`E`) but keeps count of how many matches/changes in `n` and stops making those changes when `n` becomes higher than 9.

```
n = 0

For i = 1 To E
    If n < 10 And Cells(i, 15).Value = s3 And Cells(i, 13).Value = rA And Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
        Cells(i, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You managed to understand my problem and make a super simple magic solution. I did end up adding the line the other person included, but I really appreciate your answer

Comment: No problem. See my comment on Xabier's answer for the reason I wrote it the way I did. Glad you're happy either way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depending what exactly you are doing, looping trough columns and rows in Excel is a standard task. Let's assume that your task is to generate some data in 20 Excel columns like this:

[image]

Then your task is to loop through every column of every row and to color it in red, if it is divisable by 7:

[image]

Then a solution with 2 nested loop is probably the easiest decision - one loop for rows and in every row looping through the columns:

```
Public Sub GenerateSomeData()

    Dim someRows As Long
    Dim someCols As Long

    Cells.Clear

    'GenerateSomeData
    For someRows = 1 To 100
        For someCols = 1 To 20
            Cells(someRows, someCols) = someRows + someCols
        Next someCols
    Next someRows

    'Search for values divisable by 7:
    For someRows = 1 To 100
        For someCols = 1 To 20
            If Cells(someRows, someCols) Mod 7 = 0 Then
                Cells(someRows, someCols).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next someCols
    Next someRows

End Sub
```